# Why do we fear the night?

Tags: human-physiology, light

I always feel more afraid in the dark than in light conditions. Is this a common phenomenon in all the people? Does it have biological underpinnings?

Comment: This is more a psychology question than a physiology question and is probably better asked at http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possibly related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/55700/why-are-fearful-stimuli-more-powerful-at-night?rq=1

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate as mentioned above, since the OP deemed the other question as a sufficient answer for this one.

Comment: Our ancestors were hunted by predators active at night. This is our inheritance, it is not something pathological.